# Why is the Run button sometimes disabled in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2.

I have noticed that on some occasions, the *Run* button in Android Studio becomes disabled without any apparent reason. This can be seen in the attached Image A.

This problem persists even after rebuilding the project. However, I have found that I can resolve the issue by closing and reopening Android Studio.

What could be causing this issue with Android Studio?

**Image A**
[image]

Comment: When this happens, check the Build tab at the bottom of the screen for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when this happens, you just have to click the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button to resolve it.

[image: gradle sync]

Answer (score 0):

Click Run on the menu and then Edit Configurations... then click on Android Application on the left and click the + button. Choose Android Application from the pop-up menu. Then pick the module (its normally app or something like that). Then click apply and ok.

If you have more errors after that, try to re-import the project in Android Studio.

If this doesn't solve your problem, something I noticed is that while Android studio is loading, the button can be disabled while necessary libraries load. In addition, if you have not specified a device to run the code on or have compiling issues the button may be disabled too. Good luck!

(Credit to Thanos)